# sed inside expect script send command

Tags: linux, sed, expect

I m using `sed` inside `expect` script send command as mentioned below and getting the below error. Please let me know what am I missing here.

```
set new '"$Backend1Name"'
spawn ssh '"${userid}"'@'"$Backend1Name"'
expect "?*assword:*"
send '"$password\r"'
expect "?*~]# "
#puts [send -i $spawn_id "sed -i 's/\#rpc_address:.*/rpc_address:\ 10.31.201.219/' $file\r"]
send -i $spawn_id "sed -i 's/#rpc_address:.*/rpc_address:\ \$new/' /opt/APG/Databases/Cassandra/Default/conf/cassandra.yaml \r"
expect "?*~]# "

error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: TCL has a `regsub(n)` that performs substitutions within TCL... are you trying to rewrite the contents of the `*.yaml` file?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do with this line

```
set new '"$Backend1Name"'
```

Single quotes have no special meaning in Tcl/expect: they are literally  part of the $new value. The value of the `new` variable will be: single quote, double quote, value of Backend variable, double quote, single quote. If you have not set the Backend1Name variable in the expect script, then you should be getting an error.

You probably want

- if you want the remote shell to expand the variable

  ```
  set new {"$Backend1Name"}
  ```
- if you want the expect script to expand the variable, but you need the double quotes in the value

  ```
  set new "\"$Backend1Name\""
  ```

I question whether you want the literal double quotes around the name to show up in the YAML file.

You might want to have a look at lessons 5&6 of [the Tcl tutorial](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)